# What is known about NATO's plan for the safety of Poland?

Tags: russian-federation, poland

NATO is supplying weapons to Ukraine via the Polish border. This increases the possibility of the Russian attack on Poland. Coz, this supply of arms is delaying Ukraine's surrender.

A day ago Russia bombed a military facility near the Polish border.

- [Russia sends a message with Yavoriv strike but an attack on Poland unlikely](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/mar/13/russia-sends-message-with-yavoriv-strike-but-attack-on-poland-unlikely)

The above article says that an attack on Poland is unlikely. This was the same thing said when Russia was amassing troops on the Russo-Ukrainian border.

What is known about NATO's plan for the safety of Poland?

And, what is known about the Polish government's plan for possible Russian backlash?

Comment: It is hard to say what people are thinking if they are not talking about it.

Comment: Poland is a _member of NATO_ – it's a completely different situation from Ukraine.  Article 5 obliges the other 29 NATO countries to defend Poland from attack. I'm not sure what else you're looking for, since any actual details of their defense plans would be highly classified

Comment: I think it involves tanks, guns and airplanes...

Comment: Are you asking if they have specific plans for the defense of Poland during an invasion, or if they have plans to deter a potential invasion in the first place? If it's the first option I'd be surprised if any details are public, but for the second option maybe NATO has published some general deterrence plans.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I've made a small adjustment to your question to address the likely concerns of down and close voters. The current close reason is "Questions asking for the internal motivations of people, how specific individuals would behave in hypothetical situations or predictions for future events are off-topic, because answers would be based on speculation and their correctness could not be verified with sources available to the public." and simply asking what is **known about** the plan helps to avoid that issue.

Answer (score 4):

The details of the *current* NATO plan for the defense of Poland are obviously classified.

Some information about a previous plan was [leaked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Eagle_Guardian). Nine divisions would defend Poland and the Baltics. In addition to Polish divisions, there would be divisions from the US, UK, and Germany. Moving forces of this size will take weeks or months, not days, so it would be a counterattack rather than a forward defense. The Enhanced Forward Presence are tripwire units much smaller than a division.

I don't know which divisions, but presumably all of the Polish ones. [3 (UK) Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3rd_(United_Kingdom)_Division) and [1st Panzer Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_Panzer_Division_(Bundeswehr)) would appear to be a logical fit just going by equipment and location (1st Panzer Division is allocated to the [Multinational Corps North-East](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinational_Corps_Northeast)). That would leave three to be provided by the US, unless the Baltics were accounted as one division.

Comment: "Previous" meaning from around 2010, i.e. before Russia intervened militarily in Ukraine, but after the war in Georgia.

Comment: @Fizz, yes, hence my first sentence. But there are not many more divisions around today than there were ten years ago. I would not speculate if divisions got reallocated from Poland and the Baltics to southern contingencies, considering how concerned Think Tanks were about the Baltics..

Comment: re: "so it would be a counterattack rather than a forward defense."  That would imply that the invasion would run through the existing defense despite the offensive force not having been staged.  A large offensive force would take time to deploy and stage.  Which allow for more time to re-enforce the defense.  It would then become a logistics race.

Comment: @wrod, forward defense is the term for a Cold War [NATO strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirLand_Battle#Rapid_wars,_forward_defense).